# How can I wrap (or subclass) a Cython typed memoryview in order to expose new methods to a C++ class?

Tags: python, c++, oop, numpy, cython

I'm trying to write a Python interface to a fairly large templated C++ class (specifically, the [`KDTreeSingleIndexAdaptor`](https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann/blob/master/include/nanoflann.hpp#L706-L743) class in the [nanoflann](https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann) header-only library for building KD-trees).

One of the template parameters to this class is a generic `DatasetAdaptor` class, which I have to implement myself. The `DatasetAdaptor` must expose the following interface:

```
 template <typename T>
 class GenericDatasetAdaptor
 {

 // ...

 public:

      // Must return the number of data points
      inline int kdtree_get_point_count() const { ... }

      // Returns the dim'th component of the idx'th point in the class
      inline T kdtree_get_pt(const int idx, int dim) const { ... }

      // Optional bounding-box computation: return false to default to a standard bbox computation loop.
      template <class BBOX>
      bool kdtree_get_bbox(BBOX& /* bb */) const { return false; }

 };
```

I would like to be able to pass an `[npoints, ndim]` Cython typed memoryview as the input data for `KDTreeSingleIndexAdaptor`. If I were to implement a `DatasetAdaptor` in pure Cython, it might look something like this:

```
cdef class MemoryviewAdaptor:

    cdef double[:, :] data

    def __cinit__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    cdef inline int kdtree_get_point_count(self):
            return self.data.shape[0]

    cdef inline double kdtree_get_pt(self, const int idx, const int dim):
            return self.data[idx, dim]

    cdef inline bint kdtree_get_bbox(self):
            return False
```

How can I design a similar interface to a Cython typed memoryview that would expose these methods to a C++ class?

Comment: Also trying something like above. Did you solve this problem?